# Crash after failed upgrade to 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04

I tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the system crashed, tried several solutions and didn't work.

Eventually I tried to roll back to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the pen drive, chose option to erase everything and install anew and now doesn't even start.

It doesn't advance after this screen

[image]

I am totally lost, help would be highly appreciated. I already spent hours and nothing.

Comment: I think you have given the wrong info in the question. You tagged 20.04 and 22.04 but your question asked about Ubuntu Core 20. Full and accurate info is needed in any question to begin to offer help.

Comment: @David what I really meant was 20.04 LTS, I thought just by writing 20 would be implicit since it's the only LTS of versions 20.x. I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Since there is a product called Core 20 no, always state the FULL version info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself

- entered with the pen and tried Ubuntu from the pen
- with disk utility, backedup main folders, and fully formated main SSD removing all partitions
- then, error was still there, after removing the pen
- entered in recovery mode (press ESC on startup)
- updated GRUB
- activated networking
- entered in root CLI and updated all the packages with `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Now it works.

Most importantly, I lost 2 DAYS with a simple failed upgrade. Ubuntu 20.04 is LTS, thus go to software settings and deactivate warnings about new Ubuntu versions.